# How to Display and hide an image in list on clicking on it in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, custom-lists

hi i created a CustomListField and implemented "drawListRow" method to draw an image,text and another image in a row. now when i click on the list,image on the right side should disappear.
when i again click on the list it should appear again. how to do this. Please post the code.

Comment: Hi and welcome, I am sorry to inform you that we don't "post the code". We can, however, if you give us what you tryed, tell you what can be fixed or reworked. Thank you for editting your post.

Comment: you can replace the image with transparent image on click event.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it. i am new to this blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to keep track of what rows have been clicked (and therefore have images which are hidden) and which have not. I would use an array of booleans to do this.

Override the keyDown method in your CustomListField and use getSelectedIndex to figure out which row is currently selected.

In your drawListRow method note that the ListField is passed as a parameter, cast this back to CustomListField and implement a new method called isRowClicked(int index) which returns whether the row is clicked, and therefore should be drawn with or without the right hand image.

Code roughly as follows:

```java
public class CustomListField extends ListField implements ListFieldCallback{

    private static final int TOTAL_ROWS = 10; //total number of rows in list
    private boolean[] clickedRows = new boolean[TOTAL_ROWS];

    public CustomListField(){
        //do all your instantiation stuff here
    }

    public boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time){

        int currentlySelectedRow = getSelectedIndex();

                //toggle the state of this row
                clickedRows[currentlySelectedRow] = !clickedRows[currentlySelectedRow];

        //consume the click
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isRowClicked(int index){
        return clickedRows[index];
    }

    public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index,
        int y, int width) {

        CustomListField customListfield = (CustomListField) listField;

                //check whether this row is clicked 
                if(customListfield.isRowClicked(index)){

            //draw the state when the row is clicked

        } else {

            //draw the row when the row is not clicked
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What specifically is not working? Are you getting an error? Please post your updated code.